# Editing Views from Framework Folder - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to edit my views from `resources/view` but rather i have to edit from `storage/framework/views`. Why is this happening with my project suddenly. Is there a way i can change this?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is caching your views try clearing views cache

> php artisan view:clear

Comment: Is there a way to stop the caching? Because after running the command, its still caches when i open a blade

Comment: my APP_ENV is already set to local and my cache is already set to array but still the same

Comment: can you post your service provider code over here http://ideone.com and comment it